# Falling to import R/exams question to Inspera do to lack of expectedLength parameter

Tags: r-exams

I am new to R and R/exames but it looks promising so I would like to try to use it.

I am trying to import a question from R/exams into [www.inspera.com](http://www.inspera.com) by using QTI v2.1.

The question I am using is “elasticity1.Rmd” (found on https://www.r-exams.org/assets/posts/2017-10-07-static_num_schoice/elasticity1.Rmd). I am using the exams2qti21("elasticity1.Rmd") command to export the question from RStudio (as zip).

The question imports nicely into Inspera but does not work correctly because the length of the answer needs to be specified.

The expected answer is -0.111 and for Inspera to except this I need to set expectedLength to 6 (- and . also counts).

If I change expected length in Inspera to 6 the question works the way I should.

If I export the qestionset (as QTI) from Inspera I can see that the parameter is name expectedLength="6"

Sample from exported xml file:
textEntryInteraction expectedLength="6" responseIdentifier="qti21_305799036_section_1_item_1_num_RESPONSE_1_7400516"/

**My question is, is it possible to put expectedLength parameter in the question (“elasticity1.Rmd”) e.g. in the Meta-information section of the question and have it exported with QTI?**

I tried to add guesses to Meta-information part but with no luck.

I found this information on Insperas support:
https://support.inspera.com/hc/en-us/articles/360047722351-Excel-to-QTI-conversion

13. ExpectedLength

This column is required for the question type Text Entry and Numeric Entry.

Select the length of the selected interaction element. The length is chosen by entering the number of expected characters to be answered by the candidate. Predefined as 20 characters for Text Entry and 3 for Number Entry  (if the value is empty or set as 0). Add a value "number" to the specify the width with another number of characters than predefined.

Note: Make sure that this is greater or equal to the number of characters in the correct answer. If it is shorter, the candidate will not be able to answer correctly.

Suggestion would be appreciated,

yoggi

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** In version 2.4-0 of `exams` (current CRAN version at the time of writing) there is no way of accomplishing this. In version 2.4-1 (current development version on R-Forge) we have started working towards an `exams2inspera()` interface that might get you a few steps further. To try it out install:

```
install.packages("exams", type = "source", repos = "https://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

**Details:** Following a [discussion on Inspera in our R-Forge forum](https://R-Forge.R-project.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=34379&forum_id=4377&group_id=1337) we have added a new `exams2inspera()` interface to the package that calls `exams2qti21()` with (a) an adapted XML template, (b) using MathML (rather than MathJax) for mathematical notation, (c) supplements embedded without Base64. Additionally, I have just added (d) the `expectedLength` option for numeric exercises. After installing the development option you can try

```
exams2inspera(...)
exams2qti21(..., flavor = "inspera")
```

The first command employs changes (a)-(d), the second one only (d).

**Next steps:** I would expect that further problems come up or that further tweaks are needed to make everything work as intended in Inspera. And I cannot test things out myself because I haven't got access to Inspera. Hence, StackOverflow is not the right platform to track these problems. If needed, I suggest that you open up a new discussion in the R-Forge forum.